# What's the meaning of "pettinarsi a farfalla"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I would like to understand what that part, *a farfalla*, might mean in reference to a very modest man, a government official, rather old (a widower, but still young enough to marry anew). I know that *farfalla* might refer to someone who is not serious in their ways, but here this is simply not the case. It might be a name for a style of hair-cut, but I did not find anything on Google Images that might refer to this case. Here it goes (Pirandello, *Il fu Mattia Pascal*):

> *Omino lindo, aggiustato, dagli occhietti ceruli mansueti, credo che s'incipriasse e avesse anche la debolezza di passarsi un po' di rossetto, appena appena, un velo, su le guance: certo si compiaceva d'aver conservato fino alla sua età i capelli, che si pettinava con grandissima cura, a farfalla, e si rassettava continuamente con le mani.*

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know ... it intuitively seems like a symmetrical haircut...

Comment: I read the novel several years ago (1978, I believe) and I don't think I noticed the passage. I agree with Riccardo that this should be some symmetrical haircut, possibly with locks descending on the sides of the forehead.

Comment: It could be something like this:
https://books.google.es/books?id=1JvVJm98NMgC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=pettinatura+farfalla&source=bl&ots=zlx_FZARN_&sig=T6qFbcTXbfdHxf2PacdGqzWGBWM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHisONrLLRAhULXhQKHby7AtIQ6AEIGzAG#v=onepage&q=pettinatura%20farfalla&f=false.

Comment: I agree with the symmetric hairdo, but, just to be a nitpicker, let me note that here Pirandello describes how the character *pettinava*, that is, combed his hair, not how he cut it (of course, if it were not cut symmetrically, it would be difficult to comb it so).

Comment: @DaG: So maybe this character had in some way to "design" the silhouette of a butterfly as combing his hair.

Comment: I know the haircut wouldn't be the same, but I immagine someone combing "il fiocco a farfalla" which appears in the photo of the Roman feminine bust in the book I linked before: this person should in some sense "design the silhouette of a butterfly".

Comment: @Charo You think the character was partly bald? That hairdo in the book is, of course, strictly feminine, and therefore no conservative man would put his hair that way… But if he did not have much hair, then he might be able to put what remained of his hair in a butterfly-like shape by combing it…

Comment: Well, he couldn't have too little hair because it says "si compiaceva d'aver conservato fino alla sua età i capelli", but it might happen to him to be bald in the middle of the head. But we really don't know.

Comment: The meaning, as already said, seems like a symmetrical haircut but more specifically a haircut where the hair are parted in the middle. [Like this](http://blog.you-ng.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/01/riga-in-mezzo.jpg). Farfalla means butterfly and in this example the hair center parting seems the body of a butterfly while the two hair parts are the wings

Comment: @dym Thank you very much! Why don't you make this an answer? :) Actually, for me the information that this expression *does* refer to a haircut is the crucial bit: I was not sure even of that…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning, as already said, seems like a symmetrical haircut but more specifically an haircut where the hair are parted in the middle.

[Like this](http://blog.you-ng.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/01/riga-in-mezzo.jpg)

Farfalla means butterfly and in this example the hair center parting seems the body of a butterfly while the two hair parts are the wings

Comment: This is an opinion, and an already formulated one at that (as dym himself remarks), not a sourced answer.

Comment: @DaG Well, language is such a matter that opinions shared by many nearly become a truth… :) My problem was, in Russian “a butterfly hair-do” couldn't make sense under any condition whatsoever, so I just was puzzled… So, the major part of the mystery solved… As to the actual type of hair-do, the character did not have a lot of choice, I presume.